# How to convert this 'array'

Tags: entrymodel, array, plugin-feedme

With FeedMe I'm importing some data and one of them I get is a complete array that is stored a plain text field.

This array is a bunch of car options what I want to add in a table like this:

```
{% set options = entry.optionsAndAccessoiries %}

output {{ options }} = ["Achterbank in delen neerklapbaar","Airbag bestuurder","Airconditioning","Anti-slipregeling","Antiblokkeersysteem","Centrale deurvergrendeling afstandbediend","Elektrisch bedienbare ramen voor","Elektrisch verstelbare buitenspiegels","Getint glas","Hoofdsteunen achter","Hoofdsteunen voor","In hoogte verstelbare bestuurdersstoel","Metallic lak","Middenarmsteun voor","Mistlampen voor","Radio\/CD speler","Startonderbreker","Stoelverwarming bestuurder","Stoffen bekleding","Stuurbekrachtiging","Trekhaak","Verstelbaar stuurwiel"]

{% set items = options %}

 <table>
  {% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
  <tr>
    {% for column in row %}
    <td>{{ column }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But this is causing an error:

```
array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
```

Who can help me out to point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you `{{ options }}` you literally get the output that you displayed above?  i.e. square brackets and everything?

Comment: Yes correct. And when I copy/paste that to `{% set options = ["Achterbank in delen neerklapbaar","Airbag bestuurder","etc..."]` it works like a charm.

Comment: This is not working:
`{% set opties = ["Achterbank in delen neerklapbaar","Airbag bestuurder","Airconditioning"] %}

                     {% set items = opties %}

                    <table>
                    {% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for column in row %}
                                <td>{{ column }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </table>`

Comment: While this is working:
`{% set items = ["Achterbank in delen neerklapbaar","Airbag bestuurder","Airconditioning"] %}

                    <table>
                    {% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for column in row %}
                                <td>{{ column }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your options simply need to be JSON decoded. Unfortunately, Twig doesn't ship with a `json_decode` filter, so you'll need a plugin – there are [several that fit the bill over at StraightUpCraft](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins?q=json&).

Using the [JSON Decode Filter](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/json-decode-twig-filter) plugin, here's how your code would look:

```
{% set options = entry.optionsAndAccessoiries|json_decode %}
...
```